# React confetti: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use react-confetti for my app. In development everything works well. But when I try to push the app my browser renders a blank screen and gives me this warning in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at react-confetti.min.js:570
    at react-confetti.min.js:569
    at Module.<anonymous> (react-confetti.min.js:552)
    at n (react-confetti.min.js:14)
    at Object.e.exports (react-confetti.min.js:177)
    at n (react-confetti.min.js:14)
    at e.exports (react-confetti.min.js:50)
    at Object.<anonymous> (react-confetti.min.js:4)
    at f ((index):2)
    at Module.843 (main.661b6aa6.chunk.js:1)
```

My component looks as follows:

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react'
import Confetti from 'react-confetti'

class IndexView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
    }
    this.confettiDiv = createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const height = this.confettiDiv.current.clientHeight;
    const width = this.confettiDiv.current.clientWidth;
    this.setState({ height, width })
  }

  render() {
    return (<div ref={this.confettiDiv}><Confetti height={this.state.height} width={this.state.width}/></div>)
  }
}
```

I am not sure, if I can do anything about this error since it seems to happen in the module itself. Maybe someone has encountered this problem before?

Comment: I have encountered the same problem after upgrading to `react-confetti` 5.0.1. Works fine in development but breaks in the deployed build.

Comment: I filed an issue here: https://github.com/alampros/react-confetti/issues/76

Answer (score 4):

Downgrading the react-confetti version to 4.0.1 worked for me.
It seems there's some issue with the minified version.

If you don't want to downgrade change your import to this.

```
import Confetti from 'react-confetti'; --before
import Confetti from 'react-confetti/dist/react-confetti'; --after
```